# How to stop DockerOperator after another one is completed Airflow

Tags: docker, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, dockeroperator

So, basically i have an airflow dag that is as follow:

1. Operator T1 execute a container that listen on a port forever
2. Operator T2 execute a container that will use the container from T1 inside a python script
3. Operator T3 execute a python script that doesn't need the other 2 containers, but need to be executed after T2

The problem is, how can i stop container from Operator T1 after Operator T2 finished his task (failed or success)?

Basically i have the following graph

```
[T1, T2]
T2 >> T3
```

One solution was to add a forth operator that try to kill the first container created like using

`docker stop container_name`

But i don't know how to do this

The problem is that, since T1 run foverer, the dag won't stop.

PS: I can't set a limit of time, i don't know how much time T2 will take

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you run your `docker stop container_name` inside BashOperator?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! i tried doing so like this:

`t3 = BashOperator(
    task_id="t3",
    bash_command='sudo docker stop container_name',
    )`

But i got the following error:

`sudo: docker: command not found`


Maybe i don't have to use sudo?